# MYSQL Database is slow in start up

Tags: mysql, performance

I created a database in mysql (called-test), and I'm trying to select the database using "use test", but it's not selecting the database quickly. It's slow in start up.

The following is the message I get.

```
**c=shiva s=localhost parth (none)> use test;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A**
```

How should I quickly start up the database?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: If its a new database then selecting it should be quick. Perhaps its time to upgrade the hardware...

Comment: just how 'slow' is it in starting up?  are you assuming it's slow because of the message you're receiving?  do you have other processes running on the same machine?  unless there's something else going on in that machine, 'use test' should be nearly instantaneous.